# validation failed in polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

When I do a migration I get the following error 
"ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Huntinganimals must exist"

I'm not sure where I would declare "huntinganimals".

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :camera_model
  has_one :animals, :as =>:HuntingAnimals
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :animals, :as =>:HuntingAnimals
end
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :HuntingAnimals, :polymorphic => true
end


class CreateAnimals < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
        create_table :animals do |t|
        t.references :HuntingAnimals, polymorphic: true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `t.references` in a migration, the first argument must the the name of the table, not the name of the model. So, for your model `HuntingAnimal` the table is likely called `hunting_animals` and so you'll want to reference the singular version of the table name, so: `t.references :hunting_animal, polymorphic: true`

You would also want to make that change in all of your models.